# html video does not adjust fast enough while changing the slider

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to make a videoslider, so the user can slide through a video actively.
As soon as the slider value changes, the video frame should too. But right now it's very juddery.
Only if you move the slider slowsly, the value change effects the video frame immediately.

I thought about using requestAnimationFrame but it doesn't seem to work out for me.

This is what I have so far. I appreciate any help:

```html
<style>
 
#sliderClouds{
  width: 100%;
}

  </style>
<div class="vidWrapper">
    <!-- ###########################SLIDER Video HTML STart #################################### -->
    <!-- Video -->
    <video id="videoClouds" preload="auto">
      <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Test_movie.webm" type="video/webm">
      <p>
        Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.
      </p>
    </video>
    <!-- Video Controls -->
    <div id="video-controlsClouds">
      <input type="range" id="sliderClouds" step="1" value="50">
    </div>
</div> 

<script>

/*##############SLIDER VIDEO JS Start####################*/
const videoClouds = document.querySelector("#videoClouds");
const seekBarClouds = document.querySelector("#sliderClouds");
let timeClouds;

videoClouds.onloadedmetadata = () => {
  timeClouds = videoClouds.duration * (seekBarClouds.value / 100);
  videoClouds.currentTime =  timeClouds;
};


// Event listener for the seek bar
seekBarClouds.addEventListener("input", () => {
  // Calculate the new time 
    timeClouds = videoClouds.duration * (seekBarClouds.value / 100);

    // Update the video time
    videoClouds.currentTime = timeClouds;

});

/*##############SLIDER VIDEO JS End####################*/


</script>
```

Comment: is there any difference if the video is fully loaded/buffered vs still streaming?